# How to integrate Play Framework with PostgreSQL to execute Applications?

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework

I am new to PostgreSQL, as I have installed it(version: 9.5) and doing the integration with Play Framework(version: 2.2.3), and the database driver is downloaded and can see the message, I did it using the [link](https://livinginaplay.wordpress.com/2012/08/22/playframework-2-0-and-postgresql/).But, my requirement is that How can I write sample examples using both(Play Framework or scala with PostgreSQL) ? How can I integrate them both to run any sample applications ?Please provide me any documentations or any links to execute the sample applications. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood your questions, therefore I'll answer a few more cases.

If you have set up Postgresql as described in your link then you are ready to go.
All you need now is a persistence layer.

There are a few out there:

The first one is [Anorm](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaAnorm)

[Here is a CRUD application called computer database](http://www.typesafe.com/activator/template/computer-database-scala) which shows how to use it with Anorm.

Then there is [Slick](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/PlaySlick), here is the [computer database example again but this time with Slick](https://github.com/playframework/play-slick/tree/master/samples/computer-database)

If you just want to run migrations, for example sample data then you have to create a folder called default under the conf folder like described [in the docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Evolutions)

Then just put your 1.sql file into that directory.

The structure should be like:

/conf/evolutions/default/1.sql

**1.sql**

```
# Users schema

# --- !Ups

CREATE TABLE User (
    id int serial,
    email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    fullname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    isAdmin boolean NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);



# --- !Downs

DROP TABLE User;
```

Play should 'automagically' pick up the changes and ask you if it should apply the script.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have setup like PostgreSQL installed, Play Framework installed and downloaded the database jar with my link. Actually I need to save some json files in PostgreSQL database using Play Framework, so that I need to know that how can I do it ? Please help me.

Comment: @Dhana check out the official docs [Play working with Json](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJson)

Comment: I am already generating json files(using AngularJS), my remaining thing is that I need to save those files in PostgreSQL database on my clicking of Submit button.

Comment: @Dhana I would suggest that you check out the examples I have provided, there are many examples also on how to make ajax requests to play applications.